# SqlConnection error vs2015 with C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I work with VS 2012 and SQL Server 2012. When I changed to VS 2015 & SQL Server 2014, my `SqlConnection` didn't work and causing errors that the servers could not be found.

My code:

```
SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(local); Initial Catalog=jood; Integrated Security=true;MultipleActiveResultSets=true");

public Form1()
{
    cn.Open();
    cn.Close();
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

Error

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll
>   Additional information: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

Comment: `Data Source=(local)` => is this correct? Use local SQL Server instance name, `.\SQLEXPRESS` or LocalDB as data source name.

Comment: Data Source=(local) working perfectly before

Comment: Check your current connection string against this list: https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/. Since you're using `Initial Catalog` parameter, better to use `Data Source=[LocalSQLServerInstanceName]`.

Comment: thank you but i figured that my problem is with the sql server, back to 2012 when i use "(local)" or "." for server name it works but here with sql server 2014 i have to write the server name, did i missed anything when i installed sql server 2014?

Answer (score 1):

If you plan on declaring your SqlConnection property outside of a method, you need to set an access qualifier (public, private, whatever). Try using localdb instead of local as well. Do your initialization **before** you do your connections.

If this still isn't working, check your Sql configuration settings and make sure you have access to the database with your windows credentials instead of just an sql login like sa/sa

```
public SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(@"data source=(localdb);initial catalog=jood;Integrated Security=true;MultipleActiveResultSets=true");

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    cn.Open();
    cn.Close();
}
```

Tried this just now with VS2015 and SQL Server 2014 - Worked fine.

EDIT: If you can, try explicitly telling it your server name rather than using localdb.

Comment: Should it be `(localdb)\[InstanceName]` or `(localdb)\[version]` instead of just `(localdb)`?

Answer (score 0):

Check to be sure that "Initial Catalog=jood; is the same as on your sql DB. 
The error basically means it can't find that DB you're trying to connect to.

Comment: No, the error actually means it cannot connect to the **server / instance** of SQL Server - so that means the connection string is wrong - it has nothing to do with a database on the server/instance later on ..

Comment: Oh okay, I guess yours is a better explanation. When I had this same error, it was just a mismatch in the spelling the DB name (wrong connection string as you just said), that was what I was trying to pass across.